# How can I speed up the Gekko solver to optimize a quadratic problem?

Tags: python, gekko

```py
GSP_G = ['_P']
for g in GSP_G:
    kk = len(emb_units[g])   
    nn = len(nodes[g])
    nodes_list = list(nodes[g])
    SP = range(1, Sett_time_period + 1)

    Met_Vol = {}
    for n in range(nn):
        for t in SP:
            Met_Vol[t, g, n] = Metered_Volume[t, g, nodes_list[n]]

    m = GEKKO()           # Initialize gekko  m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    m.options.SOLVER = 3  # APOPT is an MINLP solver = 1
                          # IPOPT is an MINLP solver = 3
    m.options.IMODE = 2
    m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 1

    # Variable
    b = m.Array(m.Var, (kk, nn), lb=0, ub=1)

    # Constraint
    for k in range(kk):
        m.Equation(sum(b[k, :]) == 1)

    # Define the objective function
    for n in range(nn):
        for t in SP:
            m.Obj(sum([(MV_total[t, g] - \
                  (sum(b[k, n] for k in range(kk)) \
                   * Met_Vol[t, g, n])) ** 2]))
    #m.open_folder()
    m.solve()  # Solve
```

Here is a quadratic problem optimization. It contains 31440 variables (`b[k, n]`) and there is not a lot of constraints here. It's running time is so high and I need to speed up this. Is there any suggestion to speed it up?
I also tried to use `m = GEKKO(remote=False)` with both APOPT and IPOPT solvers to solve locally with both solvers but it is time consuming too.

Answer (score 0):

There are specialized solvers just for QP solutions such as [qpsolver](https://qpsolvers.github.io/qpsolvers/quadratic-programming.html). These can be faster than a general purpose Nonlinear Programming (NLP) solver such as IPOPT or a Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) solver such as APOPT. Here is a [tutorial overview of LP, QP, NLP, MILP, and MINLP](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/PythonOptimization) and how to solve them with Gekko or Scipy.

If you do want to use Gekko, the `qobj` [Quadratic Objective method](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=qobj#pre-built-objects) is a way to improve performance. The matrices can either be dense or sparse. Sparse matrices further improve performance. Here is a problem that is similar to yours from the [Linear Programming example](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/LinearProgramming), but with an additional quadratic term `x1**2+x2**2` in the objective.

**Method 1: Gekko Equations**

The equations are individually expressed with single commands with `m.Equation()` or multiple equations with `m.Equations()`. The objective is created with `m.Obj()`, `m.Minimize()`, or `m.Maximize()`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x1 = m.Var(lb=0, ub=5) # Product 1
x2 = m.Var(lb=0, ub=4) # Product 2
m.Maximize(100*x1+125*x2+x1**2+x2**2) # Profit function
m.Equation(3*x1+6*x2<=30) # Units of A
m.Equation(8*x1+4*x2<=44) # Units of B
m.solve(disp=False)
p1 = x1.value[0]; p2 = x2.value[0]
print('Product 1 (x1): ' + str(p1))
print('Product 2 (x2): ' + str(p2))
print('Profit        : ' + str(-m.options.objfcnval))
print('Solve time: ' + str(m.options.SOLVETIME))
```

*Results*

```
Product 1 (x1): 4.0
Product 2 (x2): 3.0000000013
Profit        : 800.00000018
Solve time: 0.0084000000206
```

**Method 2: QP with Dense Matrices**

The same equations are placed into dense matrix form. This can improve the model compile time because the equations are loaded as arrays. The solution efficiency may get worse than method 1 because the matrices don't exploit sparsity.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
c = [100, 125]
Q = [[2,0],[0,2]]
A = [[3, 6], [8, 4]]
b = [30, 44]
x = m.qobj(c,Q,otype='max')
m.axb(A,b,x=x,etype='<')
x[0].lower=0; x[0].upper=5
x[1].lower=0; x[1].upper=4
m.options.solver = 1
m.solve(disp=False)
print('Product 1 (x1): ' + str(x[0].value[0]))
print('Product 2 (x2): ' + str(x[1].value[0]))
print('Profit        : ' + str(-m.options.objfcnval))
print('Solve time: ' + str(m.options.SOLVETIME))
```

*Results*

```
Product 1 (x1): 4.0
Product 2 (x2): 3.0
Profit        : 800.0
Solve time: 0.0099000000046
```

**Method 3: QP with Sparse Matrices**

Sparse matrix form can improve the model compile time and solution efficiency. This is COO (Coordinate Format). Further improvement could be made with CSR (Compressed Sparse Row) format, but this isn't supported in Gekko yet.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
# [[row indices],[column indices],[values]]
A_sparse = [[1,1,2,2],[1,2,1,2],[3,6,8,4]]
# [[row indices],[values]]
b_sparse = [[1,2],[30,44]]
x = m.axb(A_sparse,b_sparse,etype='<',sparse=True)
# [[row indices],[values]]
c_sparse = [[1,2],[100,125]]
Q_sparse = [[1,2],[1,2],[2,2]]
m.qobj(c_sparse,Q_sparse,x=x,otype='max',sparse=True)
x[0].lower=0; x[0].upper=5
x[1].lower=0; x[1].upper=4
m.solve(disp=False)
print ('Product 1 (x1): ' + str(x[0].value[0]))
print ('Product 2 (x2): ' + str(x[1].value[0]))
print ('Profit        : ' + str(-m.options.objfcnval))
print('Solve time: ' + str(m.options.SOLVETIME))
```

*Results*

```
Product 1 (x1): 4.0
Product 2 (x2): 3.0
Profit        : 800.0
Solve time: 0.010500000004
```

The solution time is the worst for this simple case. Improved efficiency is expected when the number of variables increases.

**Pre-processing Reduction**

One other method to improve efficiency is to pre-process the model with  `m.options.REDUCE=3` to eliminate equations that can be explicitly solved and eliminated before handing the problem to the solver. The number is the cycles through the model to identify and remove equations.